# How to inflate fragment layout in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using fragments for Tabs, and I have a `Fragment` in which I am capturing image from device gallery.

For this I am using following code in Fragment 1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 2);
```

It works fine , as I can choose image from gallery, and for taking that Image I am using

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    try {
        // We need to recyle unused bitmaps

        LayoutInflater inflater = 
                (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
        Drawable d=Drawable.createFromPath( getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));

        LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, null, false);
        //LinearLayout l2=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_layout, container, false);

        Toast.makeText(this, getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Button btn=(Button)l.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        // btn.setBackground(d);
        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        l.removeView(btn);

        l.addView(btn);

        // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}// end of the onActivityResult
```

But unfortunately I can not see Image on btn , Even any change in Layout is not effecting in the original layout, so please help how can I inflate layout of Fragment in `FragmentActivity`, so that I can show taken image on that fragment.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please mark the appropriate answer as accepted or create your own answer and accept, to clear for the unanswered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Check your code inside `onActivityResult()`. You are creating the Inflater object directly which is not possible in Fragments. You have to create Inflater Object with respect to FragmentActivity reference. Replace this line :

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = 
                        (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

with

```
LayoutInflater inflater = 
                        (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```